# float: left makes clear: both stretch div to full height

Tags: css, css-float, clearfix

I'm creating a full width website where you have a header, a left sidebar and the rest is the main content.
It should look like this:

```
+--------------------------------+
|  header                        |
+---------+----------------------+
|         | div1                 |
| sidebar | div2                 |
|         |                      |
|         |                      |
```

The html and css looks something like this (but with more elements): http://jsfiddle.net/7QJC5/

As you can see, if i set sidebar to `float: left`, the cleared div1 stretches to full height.
I found a workaround by positioning the sidebar manually:

```
position: absolute;
top: 60px;
bottom: 0;
left: 0;
```

but i'm not sure it's the best solution.

Can anyone explain why is this and how can i solve it, or is the `position: absolute` method ok?

Comment: Remove the clearfix class from your first div: `<div class="div">aaa</div>`.  Any element (in the right pane) that you add clearfix to is going to stretch to the bottom of the sidebar's height.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For your two problems :

1. You can add  `overflow:hidden;` to `#content`. So your clearfix rule
   on child will be applied only inside #content, **it won't mind
   anymore your floatting side bar** : **[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/7QJC5/3/)**

   Make it simple, trigger layout. Make a search on dealing with
   floatting element. There's many ways depending on result you look
   for .
2. For the scroll bar, swap to another box-model to include the padding into the 100%; height, Add : `box-sizing:border-box` to `#main`. **[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/7QJC5/4/)**

Answer (score 1):

I wouldn't do it like this. For layout, i prefer to use `display:table` and `display:table-cell`. But talking about your situation:
The reason for the div1 to stretch, is because it is clearing the float, when you applied `clearfix` class to it. So float won't apply on the div2. Instead, set it to the wrapper div (#content) and it will work fine.

```
<div id="content" class="clearfix">
    <div class="div">aaa</div>
    <div class="div">bbb</div>
</div>
```

http://jsfiddle.net/7QJC5/2/

Once again, I advise you to layout through `display:table` properties, as it works better on a cross-browser level.

Answer (score 0):

Here I've use a little different approach to achieve the same effect. Check the **[DEMO](http://jsbin.com/wewizisa/1/edit)**.

--CSS CODE--

```
#header{background:red; width:100%; height:50px;}
#main{width:100%; height:100%; border:1px solid black;display:table;}
#sidebar{background:gold;}
#content{background:purple;}
#sidebar, #content{display:table-cell;}
```

--HTML CODE--

```
<div id="header">HEADER</div>
<div id="main">
    <div id="sidebar">SIDEBAR</div>
    <div id="content">
        <div class="">aaa</div>
        <div class="">bbb</div>
    </div>
</div>
```